# SFMC import failure

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, import

I have a file drop import automation that has recently started throwing a "Data Extension not found" error, but the import worked fine before and since.  The automation has run successfully 99% of the time.  I can't find any documentation about that specific error.

Comment: Well it’s quite cleat what "Data Extension not found" means: the Data Extension (table) into which data was being imported is no longer there, maybe one of the users deleted it?

Comment: but it is there, as the import has run successfully 50+ times since the error.

Comment: I’d open a support case